# Publish broken in new ASP.NET CORE project in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I create a new ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 RC from the default template.

Thereafter I right click on the project and select publish. I then need to create a profile and click on New Profile but as soon as I do I get the following error message

[image]

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 RC has stopped working

How do I publish an ASP.NET Core project in Visual Studio 2017 RC?